# React instant chat app: How do i check a user has not bypassed the join page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm in the final stages of developing a basic React instant chat messaging using Socket.io & React-Router to teach myself some core concepts.

I've been using this project on GitHub as a reference:
https://github.com/simpletut/react-real-time-chat-app

with a live version here:
https://react-chatapp-frontend.herokuapp.com/

I'm using React-Router to redirect the user from the join page (where they can choose their username and room, which is then added to the URL as variables) to the chat page.

ie. a user joining 'room1' with the username 'john' will be redirected to: http://localhost:3000/chat/room1/john

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/chat/:room/:name" element={<Chat />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Join />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}
```

However, currently there is nothing stopping a user from entering a chat room without having been redirected from the join page. This also means users can 'create' rooms, just by entering the a URL. I would like the user to be redirected to the join page or root, or just not have access to a chat room without having been redirected there first.

In my chat page, I'm using `useParams()` to get the route parameters to then join the room.

```js
  let { name, room } = useParams();

  const [currentUser, updateUser] = useState(name);
  const [currentRoom, updateCurrentroom] = useState(room);
  const [users, updateUsers] = useState([]);
  const [currentMessage, updateCurrentMessage] = useState('');

  const formRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      addMessage(prevMessages => {
        return [...prevMessages, {
          username: data.username,
          time: new Date(),
          message: data.message
        }]
      })
    });

    
    socket.emit("join_room", {username: currentUser, room: room}, (err) => {
      if (err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

I've looked over the reference code several times now and just can't quite figure out what they've done differently that's given them this verification. Does anyone know how best to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try to add some state to history when redirecting to the chat room page:

```
navigate('/chat/room1/john', {state: {from: JOIN_PAGE}})
```

Then you can check the `from` value in your chat room component:

```
const location = useLocation();
if (location.state.from !== JOIN_PAGE) {
  navigate(JOIN_PAGE)
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me, however I'm using react-router v6, so there is no history object. History seems to have been replaced with the useNavigate hook? I'm struggling to find good documentation, however.

Comment: Updated answer with `useNavigate` approach

Answer (score 1):

You could also store somewhere (for example **using redux**) the room the user is in.

If you have this information, you can have a shared Route for all chats,

```
<Route path="/chat" element={<Chat />} />
```

Then processing the state, like loading the room or something, and then getting the information of the chat the user is in within the component "Chat"

```
const roomOfCurrentUser = useSelector(getCurrentRoomSelector());
```

**OR**

directly pass the room identificator in the state

```
navigate('/chat', {state: {roomId: 123}})
```

If you still want to this with route with names of room and user, you could still store the current chats that already exists, and show the user some error or redirect if the chat does not exist